# Lein compile project with protocols

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have a project with following ns:

- processor.bus <- general protocol for bus operations
- processor.core <- main class to run
- processor.pubsub <- concrete bus methods

in processor.pubsub I have following:

```
(ns processor.pubsub
  (:gen-class))

(defrecord PubsubBus [client])

; + other stuff related to this implementation
```

In processor.bus I have:

```
(ns tiptop.processor.bus
  (:gen-class)
  (:import [processor.pubsub PubsubBus]))

(defprotocol SendToBus
  (send-line! [self json]))

(extend-type PubsubBus
  SendToBus
  ....)
```

The problem that Lein doesn't compile namespaces in right order. I get following error:

```
$ lein compile
Compiling user
Compiling processor.auth
Compiling processor.bus
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: processor.pubsub.PubsubBus, compiling:(bus.clj:1:1)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: processor.pubsub.PubsubBus, compiling:(bus.clj:1:1)
```

Notice it tries to compile my ns in alphabetical order (auth -> bus -> pubsub), instead if dependency order.

Of course I could precompile pubsub.clj before, like:

```
$ lein compile processor.pubsub
$ lein compile processor.bus
$ lein compile
```

But it doesn't seems quite right for me. What if I'll have more such dependent namespaces?

How I can tell Lein in which order it should compile my namespaces? Or maybe i'm missing something to configure in `project.clj`? I have `:aot :all` if it matters

Comment: Are you sure that it's just alphabetical order? Have you tried changing the names of your namespaces and recompiling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leiningen does not do anything to determine namespace dependencies - it simply compiles the namespaces that you tell it to. It is the Clojure compiler that handles namespace dependencies via the `require` (and obsolete `use`) built-ins.

In this case, you need to `:require` the namespace that defines the generated class before you can import it. Otherwise, you're relying on the imported class being present on the classpath as a side effect of some other operation (loading the namespace that defines it in the REPL, a previous `lein compile` command, etc). Adding an explicit `:require` in the namespace definition ensures the class is defined before it's imported:

```
(ns processor.bus
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [processor.pubsub])
  (:import [processor.pubsub PubsubBus]))
```

A couple of other notes:

- I doubt `:gen-class` is doing what you think it's doing in these namespace declarations. It does not cause class files to get written for the protocol and records defined in these namespaces; that's what the `:aot` key is for in the Leiningen `project.clj`. The `:gen-class` flag as it's used here will cause classes named `processor.bus` and `processor.pubsub` to be generated.
- It's unusual to see protocol implementation details for concrete record types specified via `extend-type` in the same namespace where the protocol is defined. The typical use case for `extend-type` is to extend your protocol to work with types that are beyond your control, like those built in to Clojure or defined in third-party libraries. When the protocol and record are defined in the same project, it's more common to see the protocol implementation defined inline as part of the `defrecord` body.

Comment: thank you! I remember I had similar dependencies that were compiling in right order, was wondering why. now I know that it was because of require in addition to import